# Is ball valve handle fixable?

Tags: plumbing, valve

Today I tried to close main water valve in my flat. The hadle broke off and I want to know, if it is fixable, as I replacing would require closing main valve for whole building (or I think it will).

I can not see any broken metal / plastick, the handle just "stayed in my hand". See photos.

Is this somehow fixable, or the valve needs to be replaced?

[image: handle]
[image: water valve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the whole valve will require replacement. The valve handle assembly looks like it was originally attached to the ball in the valve by a press fit on this part of the handle:

[image]

It is not at all clear how you could re-install the press fit part without the original type of tooling used by the valve manufacturer.

Comment: That, and the stop tab is broken off on one side (as though it was forced in the wrong direction). Even if you could reattach it it would be likely to fail again.

Comment: If it is a press fit, then surely it could be pressed back in with some sort of modern epoxy or other metal adhesive to hold it. Or put in a new handle which has ribs which bite into the receiving depression in valve stem. Just be sure to get the handle in the correct position. I saw a plumber wrench on a valve of mine and yank it over the stop in the wrong direction!

Comment: @JimStewart - I do not see that as a particularly viable approach. The press fit into the ball will act as a piston against any type of adhesive you try to put in there and keep the part from being 100% pressed into place. If any excess adhesive does squeeze out it will undoubtedly interfere with the internal ball seal inside the valve.

Comment: Aren't there replacement handles which fit in and then are tightened in place with a screw from the end?

Comment: @JimStewart - Do you see a screw hole through the shaft of the original handle? That should fully answer you question about the type of repair that you ask about.

Comment: Michael Karas, adhesive could go wrong, but possibly could be done in a way that would work. There must be people who have made this repair in some way. Replacing the valve seems a lot of trouble and expense that people would figure out a way to avoid.

Comment: What about putting the valve handle in a cold freezer and then quickly inserting it into the valve. Maybe it would slip in when cold and then expand and tighten in place. That shouldn't cause any damage to try.

Comment: Given the amount of damage that could result from having a non-functioning water shut-off valve in an individual apartment the building may require replacement of the valve and not allow 'creative' repairs to the valve.

Comment: @JimStewart - Glad to see that you conclude that replacement of the valve is the best choice here.

Comment: Oh, I don't think that replacement is necessarily the best choice, just that it may be necessary. I would contact building management and ask them if I could explore ways to repair the valve. This kind of failure may have occurred before and they may have a solution or they may state that replacement is required ASAP. But unless thay do so I would research the matter before concluding that replacement is necessary.